# Saying Good Morning to Your Boss

Tags: work-experience

So for the past 2 1/2 years while working in a law firm, I would enter my boss's office on a daily basis and say, "Hello or Good Morning" only to be stared at (like a deer in the head lights)and ignored.  I guess in my simple mind, I thought that this was the proper thing to do--Smile and greet your boss.  I wasn't really looking for any acknowledgement, but it would have been nice to hear "Hello or Good Morning" as well once in awhile. Not sure what I am doing wrong. It is and has been my belief that my boss does not like me.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: How on earth did you manage to keep this up for two and a half *years* before realising that maybe you're doing something wrong?

Comment: your boss either doesn't like you/ thinks you're a nut/ doesn't actually know who you are or is a bit miffed that you're disturbing him/her

Comment: 2.5 years...kind of late now. Doesn't really matter. I would stop just because it's obviously not having the desired effect. I would not say he does not like you though.

Answer (score 8):

It's certainly courteous to greet your boss when you meet them in the morning, but depending on the cultural norm where you work, it may not be typical to enter their office to do so.

In the US, for example, I wouldn't disturb my boss in his office in the morning.

Your boss's response after the first few days you did this should have been a clue it wasn't as appreciated as much as you expected. I'm surprised you stuck with it for two and a half years.

Comment: Now I imagine you have to worry that if you stop abruptly your boss is going to assume you don't like *him* anymore!

Comment: Surely it is courteous to greet anybody. Small talk is the lubricant of life

Comment: @EdHeal Courteous to greet, yes. But some may see a person coming uninvited into their private space (i.e. office) as a little intrusive.

Comment: Where I work, it's normal to say "good morning" to anybody you meet while walking to your desk, and anybody else already at nearby desks.  But I wouldn't go out of my way to visit the boss' office just to say "good morning".

Answer (score 2):

Some people are morning people. Some people are best in the afternoon. Some people are weird and are best in the night.

Your boss is probably an afternoon person. So do not take it personally.

Comment: I agree. I'm a morning person but after a few months of getting one or maybe two replies from a chirpy "Good morning" when I get to work, I gave up. Sometimes it is not you, it is just not their style to partake in a morning greeting.

Answer (score 0):

Different people, different offices, different habits/customs. I know people who firmly believe no morning can ever be called good if they're awake ... and I know people who would simply be amazed that you went out of your way to be polite to the boss. Luckily I've never known anyone who would be offended by a Lowly Peon daring to intrude upon the boss's attention.

You're not doung anything wrong;  at most unexpected. Don't worry about it until/unless there's a complaint.

But also, you need to accept that some people don't see the point in responding to ritual greetings. It doesn't mean they're annoyed, just that it isn't their style. You need to decide whether to continue while knowing you won't be answered, or stop if the lack of answer bothers you.

Remember, if this is the thing you consider worth asking for advice on, that implies your job is pretty darned good in all other ways. Relax and focus on something more productive.